# What is the generalization of "left" and "right" properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory

I was looking at the usual way one proves that inverses in a group are unique, namely by supposing that they aren't and $g'$ and $\hat{g}$ are both inverses of $g$. Then

$$
g'=e*g'=(\hat{g}*g)*g'=\hat{g}*(g*g')=\hat{g}*e=\hat{g}
$$

This actually presupposes only that $\hat{g}$ is a *left* inverse and $g'$ a *right* one. The same thing happens with maps, where proving a map is bijective requires only that it is both surjective and injective. A similar thing is true of the way $\leq$ and $\geq$ and $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$ work. I was wondering if there was some (category-theoretic?) generalization of the way these work. I hope the question doesn't seem too soft or vague.

Comment: Aren't they just the usual morphism in a category and the opposite? For example, a poset turned into a category taking as objects its elements and an arrow from $A$ to $B$ if $A\leq B$, In the opposite category you've got an arrow from $B$ to $A$ (this would be the poset with the dual order)

Comment: Seeing these arrows in the same category (not taking opposite), I would say they are (or you're looking for) composable morphisms $A\to B$ and $B\to A$.

Comment: The notions of _monomorphism_ and _epimorphism_ in a general category are the right generalisations of injectivity and surjectivity, and also have some connection to left and right inverses.

Comment: @Joppy "Right" is sort of subjective here. These notions are *one* way of generalizing injections and surjections.

Comment: @Joppy Elaborating a bit on Stefan Perko's comment, we usually *don't* consider plain epimorphisms as the "right" generalization of surjection. Usually something like regular epimorphism is considered more appropriate. Wikipedia [alludes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism#Terminology) to this.

Comment: @DerekElkins Sure, but is it helpful to know this for someone starting category theory? I feel like if you pointed someone new to the definition of epimorphism, they could have some fun, and if you pointed them to the definition or regular epimorphism, they would probably back away slowly. The wikipedia page also gives, in its second sentence, the interesting example of the ring morphism $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ being and epimorphism, so I feel like there is little harm in saying "epimorphisms generalise surjections in sets".

Comment: @Joppy I'm not saying this needs to be given to people just starting category theory, and I'm not at all denying that epimorphisms generalize surjections. The issue was calling them the *right* generalization. The harm is making it sound like the important idea is epimorphism and that just happens to correspond to surjection in the category of sets. Usually having the underlying functions of a concrete category be surjective is what's important and we choose the notion of epimorphism that gives that. It takes some categorical insight to see why the situation is different for monos.

Answer (score 1):

If a morphism has a section $g_1$ and a retraction $g_2$, then it is iso and $g_1 = g_2$ is its inverse (also c.f. "split mono", "split epi").

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

If $f:A\to B$ is some arrow in some category that has a left-inverse $h$ and a right-inverse $g$ then it can be shown that $h=g$ on the way exposed in your question:$$h=h\circ\mathsf{id}_B=h\circ(f\circ g)=(h\circ f)\circ g=\mathsf{id}_A\circ g=g$$